# Complex SQL query with JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have the following tables in my database:

**tags**

```
id | name
---------
 1 | tag1
 2 | tag2
 3 | tag3
 4 | tag4
```

**map_posts_tags**

```
post_id | tag_id
----------------
    123 | 1
    123 | 2
    234 | 1
    345 | 3
    345 | 4
    456 | 2
    456 | 1
```

Is it possible to get all the posts with the same related tags as the passed `post_id` by using a SQL query?

**For example:**
I have my post with id 123 and want to get a list of all the posts that have the same tags related (excluding from the list my post with id 123 if possible from SQL).

Comment: If you have post with id 123, what's the expected result?

Comment: all of the tags? in your list only 456 qualifies right??

Comment: @ZahiroMor in my list 234 and 456 qualifies,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tags t 
    INNER JOIN map_posts_tags mpt
    ON t.id = mpt.tag_id
WHERE tag_id in (
    select tag_id from map_posts_tags
    where post_id = 123)
AND NOT post_it = 123
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you what you want. You can join it with `tags` table to get `tag name` too

<kbd>**[`SQLFiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13808/1)**</kbd>

```
select distinct post_id from  map_posts_tags where tag_id in 
(select tag_id from map_posts_tags where post_id = 123)
and post_id <> 123
```

Comment: your query returns all posts with at least one tag of the post 123

Comment: This is what OP wants if I understand the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question clearly:

```
SELECT map_posts_tags.post_id FROM map_posts_tags 
INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = map_posts_tags.tag_id
WHERE map_posts_tags.tag_id = 1
AND map_posts_tags.post_id != 123
```

Comment: this is by passing the tag id and post id to exclude. I would need to pass only the post_id if possible . Maybe nested selects are the solution

Answer (score 0):

The below query should work for you

```
  select t.*, mpt.* from tags t
    join map_posts_tags mpt on t.id = mpt.tag_id
    where mpt.tag_id in (
       select tag_id from map_posts_tags where post_id = 123)
    and mpt.post_id  123
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select post_id 
from map_posts_tags mpt 
where tag_id in 
            (select tag_id 
             from map_posts_tags 
             where post_id = 123)
  and post_id <> 123
group by post_id
having count(*)=(select count(*)
                 from map_posts_tags 
                 where post_id = 123)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the purpose of the tags table is right now but the following gives you all post_id's and tag_id's that match your selected post_id

```
DECLARE @post_id int
SET @post_id = 123
select * from map_posts_tags
where tag_id in (select tag_id from map_posts_tags where post_id = @post_id)
and post_id <> @post_id
```

As others have stated, you could join back onto the tags table if you're wanting tag names too

```
JOIN tags on tags.id = map_posts_tags.tag_id
```